# optimization for nested loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops, compiler-optimization

Can someone skilled in loops say how this task can be optimized - at least a bit? Maybe some cache? or loop un switching? 
memory limit 512 m

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MOD = 1000000007;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = i; k <= j; ++k) {
                x = (x + 1) % MOD;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What did you try so far? Where does this 'problem' come from? Because like this, I'd guess that (1) it's a homework and (2) it can be solved in closed form after some math-level optimization, regardless of implementation language.

Comment: _loop un switching_? Do you mean [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)? Usually, I leave this to the compiler which does it very probably better than me.

Comment: "at least a bit?"  You're not looking for a bit; you're looking for a lot.  Work out how many times you'll call the line `x = (x + 1) % MOD;` when n is 10, and then when n is 100.    No, a cache probably won't help you.

Comment: @dedObed is right; do a bit of algebra and you should be able to figure out how many iterations of the inner-most loop you'll perform.  Once you have that, it should be a trivial optimization.

Comment: MATH(S)! MATH(S) can do it.

Comment: I think last loop can be replaced to `x = ( x + j - i + 1 ) % MOD;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [WolframAlpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+for+i+%3D+0+to+n+sum+for+j+%3D+i+to+n+(j-i)) gives you a closed-form expression for the loop that you are calculating:

```
x = (1/6 * n * (n + 1) * (n + 2)) % MOD
```

<sup><sup>Please give us MathJax support on StackOverflow!</sup></sup>

Then, it's just a matter of turning that closed-form expression into code. Because we do not want `x` to overflow, we must occasionally perform modulo before the end of the operation:

```
long long x = n % MOD;
x = (x * (n + 1)) % MOD;
x = (x * (n + 2) / 6) % MOD;
```

With this, the number of mathematical operations is independent of the size of `n`, and certainly much faster than your loop.

Comment: You can be sure that the product is divisible by six, because there is at least one multiple of 3 and one even number in three consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: well.. you apply the modulo at the very end (in your original WA formula). Even if you don't, the modulo, if 'active', will turn one of the factors into zero, making the result trivially divisible by anything.

Comment: Actually you're right, I just need to do it before the final modulo